# Не работает setcookie()

Tags: php

Пишу авторизацию на сайте. Вот такой код

```
<?php
include('config.php');
include('funcs.php');
session_start();
$con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, 'SELECT password FROM users WHERE email=?')){
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $_GET['login']);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $password);
    mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);

    if ($password == md5($_GET['password'])) {
        $key = session_create($_GET['login']);
        setcookie('ActiveSession', $key);
        $_SESSION['useronline'] = true;
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "UPDATE users SET online=1 WHERE email=?");
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $_GET['login']);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        echo "true";
    }else{
        echo "false";
    }
}else{
    echo 'Error';
}
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

И в нем не работает лишь одна строка

```
setcookie('ActiveSession', $key);
```

Никак не могу разобраться, почему. Буду благодарен за помощь

Comment: Почему не работает, какое поведение ожидается и что происходит? Опишите подробнее что хотите сделать.

Comment: До setcookie не должно быть никакого вывода на экран: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.setcookie.php

Comment: @Artur Ожидается появление cookie ActiveSession со значением из переменной $key, чего не происходит

Comment: а вы уверены что никакой инфы не выводится до момента установки куки?

Comment: @Artur Да, я уверен

Comment: Куки будут доступны при следующем обращении к сайту. В дебаг консоли Хрома можно посмотреть какие хедеры отправляются на в браузер и обратно. Должны быть хедеры на установку кук и сами куки должны появиться при запросе следующей страницы